# Custom styles.css sheet for visual editor

Tags: functions, css, visual-editor

I am trying to use my own styles.css for inside the body of the visual editor for my pages. However, when i add

```
add_editor_style('styles.css');
```

to the functions.php page it doesnt change anything (font color, boldness, etc) inside the body of the visual editor.

I use firebug and check to see if it even loaded the styles.css and i can not find that it has anywhere.

What am i missing? Do i have to install tinyMCE for this to even work or does this work with the stock visual editor?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify a file for the editor style. Just use `add_editor_style();` in your `functions.php`, and then create a file called `editor-style.css` in your theme folder. You may want to look at some examples (e.g. Twenty Eleven) for some of the TinyMCE-specific rules, which **is** the stock visual editor you're referring to.

Comment: But the **styles.css** is the file i told to load up?

Comment: Are you sure it's `styles.css` and not `style.css`? Perhaps try using `editor-style.css` to see if it works at all. Also, be aware that TinyMCE has some pretty specific stuff it wants, and that if you have your CSS declared using IDs or classes, they are not going to show up even if the CSS file is loaded, as TinyMCE does not load in your theme's structure.

Comment: Thanks. It was reading from editor-styles.css as well that was overwriting my own styles.css! :o)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file **must** be called...

```
editor-style.css
```

for TinyMCE / Wordpress (Im not sure which) to play nice.  Oddly enough using another name will work for some of the styles.  I was using "style-editor.css" and it would show the color of the class (depending on what else was in the class), but not the font size.  I switched to "editor-style.css" and now its working perfectly.

Thank you helenhousandi for inspiring me to try this.